# Between which two points will emf be induced, due to a changing magnetic flux, in a coil

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I was studying Faraday's laws of electromagnetic induction.While solving sums based on the concept I was not able to proceed as I did not know,between which two points emf was induced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must try to identify where emf can be induced. It can be due to a motion of a conductor in a region of magnetic field or due to a changing electric and magnetic fields. If you are considering closed loops, emf is directly proportional to the time derivative of the flux through the closed loop.

For the first case, consider a conductor which is in motion in a region of magnetic field. Now the charges in the conductor will experience Lorentz force, $\vec{F}=q(\vec{v} \times\vec{B})$, due to which positive and negative charges will move to opposite directions. Now for the emf, you must consider the direction in which positive charges will be accumulated as the positive terminal of your induced battery, and the direction in which negative charges will be accumulated as the negative terminal of your induced battery. Now treat this induced battery as a normal one as you do in simple DC circuits.
In similar fashion extrapolate this concept in the other cases.

I hope this helps.

Comment: between which two points will the emf if be induced,if the loop is circular?

Comment: A circular loop is a closed loop, so even if it is undergoing a motion, there is no change in flux through the loop, unless the magnetic field is time dependent. Hence for a static magnetic field, no emf will be induced.

Comment: I saw a problem, which involved the radius of the circular loop changing in a constant magnetic field.So, in that problem between which two points will the emf be induced.